# Trigger function to check if student has classess

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I am making a database in Postgres that register students for classes.

I am stuck at creating function checking if a student that want to enroll for a course isn't having any other courses in that very time he enrolled before.

There are 6 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "semester" (
    "semester_id" serial primary key,
    "semester_describtion" varchar);

CREATE TABLE "course" (
    "c_id" serial not null,
    "c_name" varchar NOT NULL,
    "c_describtion" varchar,
    "semester_id" int,
    "startDate" DATE,
    "endDate" DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (c_id, semester_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (semester_id) references semester(semester_id));

CREATE TABLE "staff" (
    "staff_id" serial primary key,
    "staff_lastname" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    "staff_firstname" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    "staff_email" varchar(40));

CREATE TABLE "student" (
    "s_id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "s_lastname" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    "s_firstname" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    "semester_id" int default '1',
    foreign key (semester_id) references semester(semester_id));

CREATE TABLE "location" (
    "location_id" serial,
    "room_nr" int,
    "building_id" varchar(40) DEFAULT 'D5',
    "max_students" int default '10',
    primary key (location_id, max_students));

CREATE TABLE "course_section" (
    "c_section_id" serial,
    "c_id" int NOT NULL,
    "semester_id" int NOT NULL,
    "staff_id" int,
    "location_id" int not null,
    "c_section_date" DATE,
    "c_section_time" TIME default '08:00',
    "c_section_during" TIME default '01:30',
    "c_section_type" TEXT not null,
    "max_students" int default '10',
    "students" int default '0',
    check(c_section_type = 'L' OR c_section_type = 'W'
       OR c_section_type = 'C' OR c_section_type = 'I'),
    primary key (c_id, staff_id, location_id,c_section_date,c_section_time),
    foreign key (c_id, semester_id) references course(c_id, semester_id),
    foreign key (staff_id) references staff(staff_id),
    foreign key (location_id, max_students) references location(location_id, max_students)
    );

CREATE TABLE "enrollment" (
    "s_id" int not null,
    "mark" int,
    "c_id" int not null,
    "semester_id" int not null,
    primary key (s_id,c_id,semester_id),
    foreign key (s_id) references student(s_id),
    foreign key (c_id, semester_id) references course(c_id, semester_id));
```

Trigger function and trigger:

```
create function check_date() returns trigger as '
declare
date1 date;
time1 time;
begin

Select c_section_date, c_section_time into date1, time1 from enrollment e 
inner join course c using (c_id)
inner join course_section cs using (c_id);

IF EXISTS  (select e.s_id , cs.c_section_date, cs.c_section_time from enrollment e 
inner join course c using (c_id)
inner join course_section cs using (c_id)
where new.s_id=e.s_id AND date1=c_section_date and time1 = c_section_time) THEN
RAISE NOTICE  ''You have classess on that time'';
Return null;
ELSE
return new;
END IF;
END;
' language 'plpgsql';

create trigger t_check_date before insert on enrollment for each row execute procedure check_date();
```

The problem is it enables to enroll student for only one class. When I want insert into `enrollment` for a second course it shows `RAISE NOTICE` in spite of the time being different.

Comment: Your first `SELECT` in the function does not have a `WHERE` clause, which does not seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_date() 
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   course_section cs1
      WHERE  cs1.c_id        = NEW.c_id
      AND    cs1.semester_id = NEW.semester_id
      AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   enrollment e 
         JOIN   course_section cs USING (c_id, semester_id)
         WHERE  e.semester_id      = NEW.semester_id
         AND    e.s_id             = NEW.s_id
         AND    cs.c_section_date  = cs1.c_section_date
         AND    cs.c_section_time  = cs1.c_section_time))  THEN

      RAISE NOTICE 'You have classes at that time';
      RETURN null;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The table `course` is just a stepping stone we can omit for our purpose. `enrollment` and `course_section` can be joined on `(c_id, semester_id)` directly.

But you really should check for more than just *date* an *time*. You should check for *overlapping* time ranges of courses.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it but it turned out that your function works the same as mine. I mean I have the same problem, it enables me to insert one student at one course only.
I have added time and date into enrollment table and enroll students per course_section. It`s far away from what I wanted to achieve but it works for now